# SqlKata with cancellation token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cancellation-token, sqlkata

I have some long-running queries that I'd like to cancel mid execution if the API request is canceled by the browser. I'm using SqlKata to execute my queries and I don't see a param for cancellation tokens. How would I be able to have my query canceled?

I would want something like this `query.GetAsync<T>(cancelationToken: cancelationToken)`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you checked [this issue](https://github.com/sqlkata/querybuilder/issues/302) of SqlKata?

Comment: I saw the ticket but it's pretty old and I didn't see any resolution. I was hoping that by now there's a fix.

Comment: If it is not yet fix by the SqlKata community then you can find at most workarounds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the latest version of sql kata has it as one of the params. I just upgraded packages `SqlKata` and `SqlKata.Execution` to version 2.3.3 and I see it in the source code.

Alternatively, you can manually run it via Dapper by getting the SQL string and bindings from SqlKata and passing it into Dapper. I didn't test this but it would be something like this:

```cs
var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
var compiler = new SqlServerCompiler();
var db = new QueryFactory(connection, compiler);
var query = db.Query("TableName"); // write your query here

var sqlResult = db.Compiler.Compile(query);
var sqlString = sqlResult.Sql;
var bindings = sqlResult.Bindings;

await using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
var result = await connection.QueryAsync(new CommandDefinition(sqlString, bindings, cancellationToken: cancellationToken));
```

Comment: Yes it was recently added, the correct version at this date should be https://www.nuget.org/packages/SqlKata/2.3.3, the 3.2.3 was published by mistake and unlisted from Nuget

Comment: Thanks. I edited my response to the correct version.